# PostGIS - ST_Difference query returns a dissolved result

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I am using the ST_Difference to erase multipolygon feature by a mask. However, the query returns a dssolved multipolygon.

The query is the following:

```
'''SELECT ST_AsGeoJSON(ST_Collect(geom))::json
   FROM (SELECT (
     ST_Dump (
         ST_Difference(ST_GeomFromGeoJSON('%s'),ST_GeomFromGeoJSON('%s')))).geom)
             As f''' % (feature,mask)
```

Please take a look at those images to understand the problem:

Input:
[image]

Dissolved output:
[image]

Comment: You could try breaking the Multi Polygon into its components first, do the difference on each piece and then aggregate them back together

Comment: Is it possible to do this in a unique query?

Comment: Possibly, but I don't have postGIS to try it on.  I'll see if I can mock up a pseudo query for you.

Comment: Have got postgis now and tested the following query

Comment: Keep in mind that your MultiPolygon is invalid, thus will break a few assumptions.

Comment: You right, the multipolygon cannot share boundaries or intersect. That's why I got this problem. Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general process is use ST_DUMP to break the geometry into parts.  Apply a ST_DIFFERENCE to 
 each part and then collect it back together with ST_COLLECT.  I've tested this with PostGIS 2.0.1

```
SELECT ST_AsGeoJSON(ST_MULTI(ST_COLLECT(d.Geom)))::json
FROM (
    SELECT ST_DIFFERENCE(
        (P.Parts).geom,
        ST_GeometryFromText('POLYGON ((25 75, 75 75, 75 125, 25 125, 25 75))', 0)
        ) As Geom
    FROM (SELECT ST_DUMP(
        ST_GeometryFromText('MULTIPOLYGON (((0 0, 50 0, 50 50, 0 50, 0 0)),((0 50, 50 50, 50 100, 0 100, 0 50)))', 0)
        ) AS Parts) AS P
    ) AS D;
```